# Carousal indicators are overlapping in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, google-web-designer

In the website, the carousal indicators are shown as below image-
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8JjC.png)

while i want the carousal indicators as below image-
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0obq.png)

i am importing carousal from react-bootstrap/carousal and i am also using bootstap.min.css.

while i have seen some source code of carousal indicators where they are designed as li element as [third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAAFp.png)

, but in my case the carousal indicators are designed as buttons as [fourth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzyMF.png).

can you geniuses, please help me out?

Comment: Please add more info: which package do you use carousel? and its setting, etc.

Comment: Hey @LikiCrus , i havn't downloaded any additional add on. I just use the package that comes with the npm and specifically i installed npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0.